# Testing webapp in slow network

Tags: ajax, testing, web-applications

I don't know if this is the kind of question I can ask here, but here I go.

I have a ajax packed web application and some bugs show up only on slow networks (atleast probability of those bugs are higher in such an environment).
So my question is this -- is these some tool which will help to simulate a slow network for testing purposes.

Comment: I found this wonderful 'Network shaping' tool called netlimiter http://www.netlimiter.com which would let you simulate slow networks on your system.  Does my job.

Answer (score 0):

Delay some time on server-side.

You haven't told anything about your code, but it can be: started another request while previous one is in progress (not processed yet, not returned yet), timeout returned false data.